# Proof relation expectation value (QED)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-electrodynamics

I am trying to prove the following relation

$$
\langle\Phi|\hat{\bar{\psi}}(x)A\hat\psi(x)|\Phi\rangle=\bar\varphi(x)A\varphi(x)+\langle0|\hat{\bar{\psi}}(x)A\hat\psi(x)|0\rangle\,,
$$
where $|\Phi\rangle$ is a state that contains a single electron and it is defined in this way

$$
|\Phi\rangle=\sum_{r=1}^2\int d^3\!q\;f_r(\textbf q)\hat b^\dagger_r(\textbf q)|0\rangle
$$
normalized so that $\langle\Phi|\Phi\rangle=1$, and $\varphi(x)$ is the spinor defined $\varphi(x)=\langle0|\hat\psi|\Phi\rangle$.

So far I have tried to write explicitly the LHS in the mode expansion of the Dirac field operators, but I don't think this is the right approach. Any hints or suggestions on how to proceed?

Note that I have include the homework tag so please avoid giving the full answer.